# Creating multiple barplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot multiple barplots  based on the diffrent columns

A sample of my hypothetical data are as follows:

```html
df<-read.table (text=" AA   Time1   Time2   Time3   Time4   class1  class2  class3  class4
A1  46  42  82  86  35  49  96  72
A2  41  47  65  41  35  49  96  72
A3  21  73  53  96  35  49  96  72
A4  27  61  85  54  35  49  96  72
A5  99  79  32  49  35  49  96  72
A6  66  49  88  55  35  49  96  72


", header=TRUE)
```

Based on this sample, I want to get multiple bar plots. For example Time1,2,3,4 with class 1; Time1,2,3,4 with class 2 and so on.

The output: x-axis = class1   indicating bars A1, A2, A3, and A4 with class1 1. So you get A1= 46 with 35, A2= 41 with 35 and so on for class1 and I want to get the same plots for class2, 3 and 4. Finally, I have 4 separate plots with x-axis class1, 2,3, and 4.
Iwill get like this for class 1[image]

Comment: If you use the tidyverse, the tidyverse way is to manipulate the data to fit the plot. In this case, you need to pivot your data, set AA as x, values as Y, and fill to the classification (time1, class1). I will try to post an answer in 5 min

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution. After understanding the essence of your plot you can use indexes to detect the variables and the pair them one by one. This can be done with a loop and store the plots in the object `List`. After that you can wrap the plots in one using `patchwork`. Here the code and many sorry from previous confusion:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork)
#Detect variables
i1 <- which(grepl('Time',names(df)))
i2 <- which(grepl('class',names(df)))
i3 <- which(grepl('AA',names(df)))
#Create list
List <- list(length(i1))
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(i1))
{
  #Data
  mydata <- df[,c(i3,i1[i],i2[i])]
  #Reshape and plot
  List[[i]] <- mydata %>% pivot_longer(-AA) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=AA,y=value,fill=name))+
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge(0.9))+
    labs(fill='Var')+theme_bw()+
    xlab(names(mydata)[which(grepl('class',names(mydata)))])
}
#Arrange
wrap_plots(List)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Assume one plot: x-axix is Class 1. y-axis =values. you could see 4 bar plots of times each has a barplot of class 1 attached. So you get 4 pairs.(46,35),(41,35),(21,35),(27,35),(99,45) and (66,35)

Comment: @user330 I have added an update. Many thanks for adding the plot and deeply sorry for any confusion!

Comment: Not at all, it is very great now, just I wonder if I could change x-axix to class1 , class2 , class3 and class 4?

Comment: @user330 Done, I have added an update for you! Hope that helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You still need to work on the legends, or you can filter and make graphs separately.
The approach is to manipulate the data, get groupings (not necessary if you filter) and get the graph

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols= c(-AA), names_to='Classification', values_to='Value') %>% 
  mutate(Group = substr(Classification,nchar(Classification),nchar(Classification))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=AA,y=Value,fill=Classification)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
  facet_grid(.~Group)
```